# Share information between classes, Reference variables

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a little problem with share/reference the same information between classes, without duplicating values. I don't know how to resolve this in a good approach.

```
Class TestA {
     List<Double> listDouble;
     Double double1;
     Double double2;
}

Class TestB {
     Double sumList;
     Double sumDouble;
     Double sumOtherCase;

     Double otherCase1;
     Double otherCase2;
}
...
Class TestX {
     Double sumList; //another instance of 'TestA' different of the instance in 'TestB'
}
```

I have the classes 'TestA' and 'TestB' with values for example:

```
TestA.listDouble= new ArrayList<>();
TestA.listDouble.add(10d);
TestA.listDouble.add(20d);
TestA.double1 = 10d;
TestA.double2 = 20d;
TestB.otherCase1 = 10d;
TestB.otherCase2 = 20d;
```

I want to refence this values with class 'TestB', for when I change the values in 'TestA' or 'TestB' the values sums in 'TestB' change too. For what when I get TestB.sumList, TestB.sumDouble or TestB.sumOtherCase the values are updated.

Someone could help me? Sorry my English. Thank you!!

**EDIT 1:**

I have classes within classes. like Case 1: { 'TestA0' > 'TestB0' > 'TestC0' } and Case 2: { 'TestX0' > 'TestX1' }

I realise now that in the first case will be easier to use getter and setter to get the right value, because I will have a instance of a object inner, values in 'TestC0' and the sum in 'TestA0'.
Now I'm thinking about for example, I have values in 'TestX1' and a sum of this values in 'TestA0', will I be required to create a instance in 'TestA0'?

Comment: Have you ever read about [Getters and Setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)? if not, take a look at them. Also read about [Java Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) **read this 1st** before getters and setters

Comment: i think you dont undestant Java OO,

Comment: @Frakcool so, I know about Getters and Setters... Thak you very much for try help ^^... I will add a another example, about what I want to do.

Comment: @David I think I understant a little about OO. Thak you very much for try help ^^... I will add a another example, about what I want to do.

Comment: Besides getters/setters, you have to think about synchronization and locking if you care about multi-threading at all (e.g. running in a web server context). E.g. I'd have the setter for the list run `synchronized(listDouble)`.

Comment: @JoãoEduardoBertotti it's not very clear what you're asking, you might want to write your question in your language and translate it with [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com/). Btw is your native (spoken) language portuguese? (Because of your name) If so, you can post your quesion at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks for the tips... I will try there too... I'm using Google Translator... I tried wrote here, because here the answers come faster...

Comment: @JoãoEduardoBertotti ok no problem... Good luck! :)